# Silverlight & RIA Services session timeout

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

**I really cannot find any clear solution to set Silverlioght & RIA Services session timeout.**

It bothers me a lot. Every time I have to log in when I cannot see data and the message box "Please,wait..." stays only .

**I guess there is some web.config solution that I'd like to implement.**

There are some links that are not helping at all like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877315/silverlight-4-ria-services-timeout-issues) one.

*If you can please provide the complete web.config section with all settings.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to add under  `<system.web>`

this section...

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
  <forms timeout="20160"/> 
</authentication>
```

LINKS: [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/08/430011.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470777/forms-authentication-timeout-vs-session-timeout)